Authentication error when using python to access 365 office file
I am running this code to access sharepoint through Python:
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 
import io
import pandas as pd

#target url taken from sharepoint and credentials
url = '...'
username = '...'
password = "..."

# Authentication
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
    ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()
    print("Authentication successful")
else:
  print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())

ctx = ClientContext(url).with_user_credentials(username, password)
web = ctx.web.get().execute_query()
print(web.url)

I got an error saying: ClientRequestException: (None, None, '404 Client Error: Not Found for url: {file_url}/_api/Web')
How to resolve this error? Thanks for your insights!

404 isn't an authentication error. It says the URL doesn't exist

Thanks a lot!!! I change the url and it works.
